# Missing argument 3 for

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to order products by price with one link for low to high and the other high to low,
and I got this error: "Missing argument 3 for App\Http\Controllers\ShopController::products()"  when im opening the 'content.products', page.
this is the function in the controller:

```
public function products(Request $request,$category_url,$sort){
    Product::getProducts($category_url, self:: $data);
    if ($category1 = Categorie::where('url', '=', $category_url)->first()) {

       $products = Product::where('categorie_id', $category1->getAttribute('id'))->orderBy('price', $sort)->get();

        return view('content.products', self::$data , compact('products', 'sort')); 
    }
}
```

this is the route:

```
  Route::get('shop/{category_url}/sorting-{sort}','ShopController@products');
```

those are the link from the view, the view is content.products

```
  <a href="  {{ url('shop/'.$category['url'].'/sorting-asc')}}" 
 style="color:black"> High to low</a> |
    <a href="  {{ url('shop/'.$category['url'].'/sorting-desc')}}" style="color:black">Low to high</a>
```

Comment: Do you have any other routes that start with `shop`?

Answer (score 0):

Change

`public function products(Request $request,$category_url,$sort){`

to

`public function products(Request $request,$category_url,$sort = 'ASC'){`

This gives a default value to the last parameter. And to make sure also

`Route::get('shop/{category_url}/sorting-{sort}','ShopController@products');`

to

`Route::get('shop/{category_url}/sorting-{sort?}','ShopController@products');`

to make the last parameter form the url optional.

Comment: Thanks, now it doesn't show the error but the order of the products is not changing after clicking low to high or high to low